# How to init dynamic list of options with react and materialize css

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I'm doing my study project and chose materialize as css framework, i'm have some trobles with it, but i'n not want change it because i'm almost finished.

I need to add select element with dynamically generated options, i do something like this:

```
import React, {useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";
import {useHttp} from "../hooks/http.hook";
import {AuthContext} from "../context/AuthContext";

export const  Demo = () => {

  const [stock, setStock] = useState([])
  const {request, loading} = useHttp()
  const {token} = useContext(AuthContext)

  const fetchStock = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const fetched = await request('/api/whip', 'GET', null, {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      })
      const whips = fetched.map((row, i) => {
        return {id: row.id, name: row.name}
      });
      setStock(whips);
      console.log("whips: ", whips);
    } catch (e) {}
  }, [token, request]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStock();
  }, [fetchStock]);

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        {
          stock.map((row, i) => {
            return (
              <option key={i} value={row.id}>{row.name}</option>
            )})
        }
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But thiw does not work, i'm read in materialze [documentation](https://materializecss.com/select.html) what i'm must separate call for any dynamically generated select elements my page generates, but I don't understand how to do it.